# Can I make dynamic forms with dropdown or multiple choice options from Google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using the code I found online. Here I wanted to google forms option dynamic while getting the options from google sheets. My sheet has more than a thousand rows btw. when I click on run it says "Error   Attempted to execute myFunction, but could not save".

```
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(‘https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGRl68f9uQQnUTOZMhKzv3Xvu4L0OzGWMBbcs6clBmc/edit#gid=0’)
let form = FormApp.getActiveForm()

const getCurrentOptions = () => {
    let sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(‘Sheet1’);
    let data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues().map(x=>x[0]);
    return data
}
```

There are almost 2k rows so dynamic field addon I could not use.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I saw the spreadsheet you were using in your code and it contains more than 1000 rows which I assume are the options you would like to get in your form.

The limit of options in a dropdown element is 1.000, if you go above that number, the script will not work.

In case you can reduce the number of options from the spreadsheet to less than 1,000, you can use the following code to make it work:

```
var formURL = "*URL of your form goes here*";

function updateDropdown() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var sheetValues = sheet.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
 var values1D = sheetValues.flat();
 var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
 var formElement = form.getItemById(*ID of the element you would like to 
 populate with the data from the spreadsheet*);
 formElement.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values1D);  
}
```

If you are not sure how to get the ID of the target element you want to populate with the spreadsheet data, you can run this function:

```
var formURL = "*URL of your form goes here*"; 
function checkIDs(){
 var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
 var items = form.getItems();
 for (var i in items) { 
  console.log(items[i].getTitle() + ': ' + items[i].getId());
 }
}
```